# How to add itemType facet for hybris OCC

Tags: facet, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to be able to use the itemtype you can use in backoffice (image attach) in the rest api like this "https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/test/products/search?fields=FULL&query=:name-asc:**itemType:Concrete**:category:PHX";

is that possible?

im using hybris 6.4

[image: hybris backoffice]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You have to create indexed property for your SOLR configuration which indexes item type.

For that create impex:

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty; $solrIndexedType; name[unique = true]    ; backofficeDisplayName; type(code); facet[default=true]; multiValue; priority; fieldValueProvider                    ; valueProviderParameter                                              ; facetDisplayNameProvider                    ; facetType(code); facetSort(code); visible[default=true]
                                 ;                 ; productType            ; Product Type         ; string    ;                    ; false     ; 1       ; productTypeValueResolver              ;                                                                     ;                                             ; MultiSelectOr  ; Alpha
```

And  then create your resolver

```
public class ProductTypeValueResolver extends AbstractValueResolver<ItemModel, Object, Object> {

    @Override
    protected void addFieldValues(final InputDocument inputDocument, final IndexerBatchContext indexerBatchContext,
                    final IndexedProperty indexedProperty, final ItemModel product,
                    final ValueResolverContext<Object, Object> resolverContext) throws FieldValueProviderException {
            inputDocument.addField(indexedProperty, product.getItemtype(), resolverContext.getFieldQualifier());
    }
}
```

and finally create a spring bean with that resolver

```
<bean id="productTypeValueResolver" class="com.your.package.ProductTypeValueResolver" parent="abstractValueResolver">
```

After that you will get extra property in solr which will reflect your item type and you can use it on product search endpoint

Comment: thank you so much! the only thing missing in your answer is another part of the impex `
INSERT_UPDATE SolrSearchQueryProperty;indexedProperty(name, solrIndexedType(identifier))[unique=true];facet[default=true];facetType(code);priority;facetDisplayNameProvider;facetSortProvider;facetTopValuesProvider;includeInResponse[default=true];searchQueryTemplate(name, indexedType(identifier))[unique=true][default=DEFAULT:$solrIndexedType]
          ;price:$solrIndexedType           ;      ;MultiSelectOr  ;1   ;                ;          ; ;;
        `